# Eclipse code formatter missing rules

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I am unable to find these line wrapping rules for the Eclipse code formatter:

- Not starting new lines with "throws" (since easily mistaken for "throw")
- Not starting new lines with dots (e.g. when method chaining)

Have I missed those or don't they exist? Here are a few examples what the standard formatter produces and what i would like to have as a result:

**Method definition: Line wrapping for closing parentheses in front of throws**

Standard:

```
String someMethodWithARatherLongName(String someParameter) 
    throws Exception;
```

Desired:

```
String someMethodWithARatherLongName(String someParameter 
    ) throws Exception;
```

**Method chaining: Line wrapping**

Standard:

```
return new StringBuilder("Hello ").append(name)
    .append(", how are you today?").toString();
```

Desired:

```
return new StringBuilder("Hello ").append(name).append(
    ", how are you today?").toString();
```

or:

```
return new StringBuilder("Hello ").append(name
    ).append(", how are you today?").toString();
```

Any specific help regarding these settings would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Not starting new lines with "throws" (since easily mistaken for "throw")

You can achieve this with `Line Wrapping -> Method Declaration -> 'throws' clause`. Change `Line Wrapping Policy` to `Do not wrap` and the throws clause will be on the same line as the Method Declaration. You can do this for the Constructor Declaration too.

> Not starting new lines with dots (e.g. when method chaining)

It seems like this isn't possible in Eclipse, but I'd appreciate such a setting too.

Answer (score 0):

I think above question was to insert new line after method declaration where we throw exceptions. I'm giving you example below.

```
public String methodWithLongName()
throws Technical Exception,Business Exception
{
    ...
}
```

I didn't find any solution so far in eclipse what you suggested was something else.